# Case Expression throwing exception

Tags: oracle, case-expression

Consider the following code:

```
 Select FLAGS,
 CASE FLAGS 
 WHEN 0 THEN "10000000"
 WHEN 1 THEN "01000000"
 WHEN 2 THEN "00100000"
 WHEN 3 THEN "00010000"
 WHEN 4 THEN "00001000"
 WHEN 5 THEN "00000100"
 WHEN 6 THEN "00000010"
 WHEN 7 THEN "00000001"
 ELSE "00000000"
 END AS Test-W 
 FROM V_TEST
```

The above statement is throwing error as:

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
 00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
 *Cause:    
 *Action: Error at Line: 14 Column: 17
```

My table name is `V_TEST`, column name is `FLAGS`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: does the query runs in `SQL*PLUS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use single quote ` for the literal expressions

The column Test-W needs to be enclosed in dobule quote

```
Select FLAGS,
 CASE FLAGS 
 WHEN 0 THEN '10000000'
 WHEN 1 THEN '01000000'
 WHEN 2 THEN '00100000'
 WHEN 3 THEN '00010000'
 WHEN 4 THEN '00001000'
 WHEN 5 THEN '00000100'
 WHEN 6 THEN '00000010'
 WHEN 7 THEN '00000001'
 ELSE '00000000'
 END as "Test-W"
FROM V_TEST
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, `CASE` is verbose and easy to interpret. You could also write the same query using `DECODE` -

```
SELECT FLAGS, 
       DECODE(FLAGS, 
       0 , '10000000',
       1 , '01000000',
       2 , '00100000',
       3 , '00010000',
       4 , '00001000',
       5 , '00000100',
       6 , '00000010',
       7 , '00000001',
           '00000000')
  AS TEST-W 
 FROM V_TEST
/
```